# Facebook SDK: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 7.)

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

I'm having a problem with the Facebook SDK for iOS, specifically with `FBNativeDialogs presentDialogModallyFrom:initialText:image:url:handler`.

This is my code:

```
[ FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self initialText:nil image:nil url:nil handler:^(FBNativeDialogResult result, NSError*error){
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Result %d",result);
}];
```

It always logs:

> *Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 7.)
>   With a result of 2, which is FBNativeDialogResultError.*

I've seen other posts that suggest by setting up the Facebook account in the iOS device/simulator this problem is worked out.  I've done this and I'm still having the problem.

Does anyone know anything more about this error or how to resolve it?